# AIX: show video card

Tags: aix, graphic-card

How to know wich video card is present in my aix workstation?
I have tried:

```
lsdev |grep video
lsdev|grep vga
prtconf
```

but no info.
I see a vga is installed on workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found

```
lscfg |grep -i Graphic
+ lai0             U787F.001.DPM5MVH-P1-C2-T1       GXT135P Graphics Adapter
```

Comment: and switches -v -l lai0 give also detailed info